# Feature preprocessing for neural nets

Tags: neural-networks, data-transformation, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

Suppose that you have a feature where for some instances the value is exactly 0, while for others it is a continuous value.

An example could be money earned doing some specific type of work, or distance covered on a bicycle for the month, etc.

Clearly, 0 is *not* the result of censoring or some missing data pattern. At the same time, the distribution seems problematic for use in a neural net, especially when there are many (unrelated) variables with such a distribution.

In a linear model, I could create a dummy for whether the variable is equal to 0, then set 0's to missing, mean-impute and center. This would have the result that the continuous part of the variable would not contribute to the result for the 0 spike, where the dummy would kick in, and would contribute otherwise. But I am weary of doing the same with a net as it is unclear to me that, after passing through a non-linearity, this would still make sense.

What preprocessing would you recommend?

[image: Example histogram of a feature with the properties in question]

Comment: Why do you think this is problematic for a NN?

Comment: Two reasons: 
1. The modal activation here is very far from the mean & median. This can be problematic in SGD with small batch sizes, for example, where we can get a very badly biased gradient.
2. There needs not be a monotonic relationship between the variable and the target, and it doesn't seem obvious for gradient descent to pick up on the fact that 0 might be, in a way, special. In a domain where data is scarce compared to the noise, I'd rather make learning as easy as possible.

Comment: Doesn’t the universal approximation theorem have continuity conditions? It makes sense to me to have on/off switches like you describe somewhere in the network, in order to make a piecewise-continuous regression function.

Comment: @Dave the function sought should be continuous, but the approximation just needs to be good on compacts, so this case is covered. But my worry goes beyond whether the net can represent the function I am seeking. I want to make sure that it can *learn* it through some flavor of SGD.